# Ordering get_categories() result by predetermined order

Tags: php, wordpress, include

I want to know why `get_categories()` is auto ascending. I want to return an array, based on the order in which category IDs are included.

This is my code.

```
<?php

$args = array(
    'include'=> '5,4,7,6',
);
$cats = get_categories($args);

?>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure why you would use `get_categories()` at all, since you already know the order you're looking for, as well as the target IDs.

Instead, I would use [`get_category()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_category), and generate the `$categories` array with a simple `foreach` loop:

```
$categories = array();
$cat_ids = array(5,4,7,6);

// A simple foreach loop, to keep things in your required order
foreach ( $cat_ids as $id ) {
    $categories[] = get_category( $id );
}
```

Comment: I usually just write a simple wrapper function in which I get my categories/terms as usual and then use `usort()` to sort my results according to the order passed to my function ;-)

Comment: @PieterGoosen , good idea. That would definitely require fewer database queries.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the Wordpress function reference

[wordpress function reference](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_categories)

Basically you need to pass arguments array to the get_categories function

```
$args = array(
  'orderby' => 'name',
  'order' => 'ASC',
  'include' => '5,4,7,6'
 );

$categories = get_categories($args);
```

EDIT:

```
$args = array(
'orderby' => 'ID',
'order' => 'DESC',
'include' => '5,4,7,6'
 );

$categories = get_categories($args);
```

Comment: Yes but if I put  that code it will order by asc  but I don't want it to be ascending order I just want to output it base on my number in include.

Comment: You can set Desc order.

Comment: Here is what you are allowed to do: orderby 
    (string) Sort categories alphabetically, by unique Category ID, or by the count of posts in that Category. Valid values:

        ID
        name - Default
        slug
        count
        term_group

Comment: And ---  order 
    (string) Sort order for categories (either ascending or descending). The default is ascending. Valid values:

        ASC - Default
        DESC

Comment: So it will turn to  7,6,5,4 . right??    It will not output as 5,4,7,6

Comment: Yes. Try it. I am not sure.

Comment: I need to output it without the use of asc and desc ,

Comment: According to the wordpress function reference you can only do what is described. What kind of sorting doesn't have asc or desc order?

Comment: Yes your right but how it will output base on what I want? I'm stock to this problem.   T_T

Comment: I can't find any other function that would return the raw set of categories. You have many other options. 1) Write sql query to retreive the raw set of categories or 2) you can use get_categories and then in a loop to reorder your categories by the algorithm you want to the set to be ordered.